# Rails 3.1, Factory girl bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

Fixed. There was a bug in Rails. See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2333

I have a problem with Factory Girl Rails and Rails 3.1.0.rc5

When I do more than once `user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)` I have an error.

```
 Failure/Error: user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant User::User
 # ./app/models/user.rb:17:in `generate_token'
 # ./app/models/user.rb:4:in `block in <class:User>'
 # ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I can create as many user as I want using Factory but only in rails console.

Tests:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Users" do

  describe "signin" do

    it "should sign in a user" do
      visit root_path
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      within("div#sign_in_form") do
        fill_in "Name", with: user.name
        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
      end
      click_button "Sign in"
      current_path.should eq(user_path(user))
      page.should have_content("signed in")
    end

    it "should not show new user form on /" do
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
          visit root_path
      page.should_not have_css("div#new_user_form")
    end
  end
end
```

factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |f|
    f.sequence(:name) { |n| "john#{n}" }
    f.fullname  'Doe'
    f.sequence(:email) { |n| "test#{n}@example.com" }
    f.password 'foobar'
  end
end
```

model/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  attr_accessible :name, :fullname, :email, :password
  before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :fullname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 }
  validates :email, format: { with: email_regex },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, length: { maximum: 30 }
  validates :password, length: { in: 5..25 }

  def generate_token(column)
    begin
      self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
  end
end
```

`User.exists?(column => self[column])` causes the problem.

Comment: That is weird, and fixing the root problem would be better, but one thing you may want to do (good practice in general) is to create your user in a `setup` method. It then becomes available for all proceeding tests.

Comment: Is this fixed now? Please accept an answer...

Comment: There was a bug in rails which caused that. See this https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2333 for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Somehow the class is not properly looked up, and I am not sure how this is happenning but could you try accessing it differently:

```
def generate_token(column)
  begin
    self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while self.class.exists?(column => self[column])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extra line i your factories.rb, it should read like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define :user do |f|
  f.sequence(:name) { |n| "john#{n}" }
  f.fullname  'Doe'
  f.sequence(:email) { |n| "test#{n}@example.com" }
  f.password 'foobar'
end
```

Comment: I'm using git version of Factory-girls and your code doesn't work. `/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-2.0.1/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:6:in define': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
` See documentation: [link]https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

Comment: try using Factory.define instead of FactoryGirl.define. You might need to try the factory_girl_rails gem

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
FactoryGirl.define  do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "john#{n}" }
    fullname  'Doe'
    sequence(:email) { |n| "test#{n}@example.com" }
    password 'foobar'
  end
end
```